# Where can I ask a question about an error I'm getting in Debian?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, linux

This question is about an error of a sign of `MikTeX` in my computer with Debian. This error is

> E: El repositorio «http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch InRelease» no
>       está firmado.

This means that:

> The repository «http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch InRelease» is not signed

when I write `apt update` in the terminal. I don't know if its topic is Tex-LaTeX, Unix & Linux, or Stack Overflow. I'm going to make this question on Stack Overflow, but I think it is off-topic.

Comment: I sincerely don't understand the downvotes. The OP doesn't know where to ask the question, therefore ask it here where should it go. "I'm going to make this question in Stack Overflow" is future tense to me. why give a hard time to the OP?

Comment: I would guess that the down votes are because the user is talking like they understand this is off topic for Stack Overflow, but they're still going to post it there, rather than waiting to find out where people think it goes here.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding and sorry for my english, If you understand me, please, redact this better than me

Answer (score 5):

Looks like an apt error - it is OS level. Might fit into U&L or Super User, though, an approximate translation of the error would help.

Comment: Done, the error means `The repository «http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch InRelease» is not signed`

Answer (score 3):

Well if you think it's off-topic at Stack Overflow, why do you want to try there first? You have two other sites to try. Pick one of them and just ask your question. If that site decides your full question doesn't belong there, they'll help you find the best place to ask it.

Answer (score -1):

My guesses would be Unix & Linux or, due to Ubuntu being Debian based, AskUbuntu.  But that's just a guess.  Given the package, the Tex-LaTex option would not be clearly wrong either.

Comment: Debian is not on topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Guesses aren't really a good thing when suggesting where a question belongs. As @JourneymanGeek pointed out, your guess about Ask Ubuntu is wrong. Saying that it's on topic there is like saying you can ask Unix questions on Ask Different because macOS is based on Unix.